# Adding an Ubuntu 20.04 machine to Windows Credentials?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

a few days ago I had a Samba server up and running on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine so that I can access its external drive from my Windows 10 desktop in the file explorer.

However, I accidentally removed the credentials of the Ubuntu machine in the Windows Credential manager:

[image]

Now when I enter the Ubuntu machine's IP address into the Windows file explorer address bar, the network folder no longer appears and it just says "This folder is empty."

So in order to add the Ubuntu machine's credentials back in, how would I enter it on this page so that I can access the network folder again? (also I didn't set up a password to the network folder)

[image]

Comment: What happens if you attempt to Map Network Drive, then enter the IP of the Ubuntu machine?  Does that then ask for credentials.  Restart the Ubuntu machine first.

Comment: No, I just get an error message that says "Windows cannot access *IP address* Error code: 0x80070043 The network name cannot be found." But I know for sure the network folder is working, because I'm able to access it from another Windows 10 laptop, but I just can't access it on my desktop.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. I have Samba running on Ubuntu and can access from Windows 11 / 10 just fine. Try running DISM / SFC on the affected machine.

Comment: Just tried running DISM and SFC then rebooted, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got the network folder to appear.
On Windows I opened the Registry Editor (Win key + R, then typing in `regedit`)

From there I navigated to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`, right-clicked (on the empty space to the right), selected `New` > `dword 32`, named it `AllowInsecureGuestAuth`

Double clicked on `AllowInsecureGuestAuth`, entered 1 into the `Value data` and hit OK.

Then I entered the IP address of my Ubuntu machine into the file explorer in Windows, and there it was, fully accessible with no errors.

Comment: I have not needed the registry to fix things since Windows NT4 Workstation